# Spark read folder directory with file names included in resulting data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I want to read all files in a nested directory, and perform some transformation on each of them. However, I also need some information from the actual path of the files. This is the current:

```py
sdf = spark.read.text(path)
sdf.show()
```

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|                 ...|
+--------------------+
|                 ...|
+--------------------+
```

However, I want something like:

```py
sdf = spark.read.text(path, include_file_paths=True)
sdf.show()
```

```
+--------------------+---------+
|               value|     path|
+--------------------+---------+
|                 ...| /a/b.txt|
+--------------------+---------+
|                 ...| /c/d.txt|
+--------------------+---------+
```

This seems like something that should be possible, but I can not find any resources describing it. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to use the "input_file_name" built-in function ? sdf.withColumn("path", input_file_name)

Comment: Boom. That was easy. Thank you! Would you write it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: What are reading from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the input_file_name built-in function as follow :

```
sdf.withColumn("path", input_file_name)
```

This built-in function is executed at Task level.